# How to style forms with jQuery UI theme

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a simple form and I want to have the labels and text fields to be colored according to the selected jQuery UI theme. The text color of labels is always black and the text fields also don't change with different themes.

Comment: Also, I noticed that firebug shows that the labels inherit color: #FFFFF from .ui-widget-content and it isn't overriden later, but the text color of the labels is black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if some of your styles don't override jquery-ui styles. Good way to do this is to use Firefox plugin: Firebug. You can inspect any html tag and see how the hierarchy of CSS affects selected element.

**EDIT:**

Sometimes Firebug doesn't show correct order of styles. Check if jquery-ui stylesheet is included after your styles and if you don't use !important class anywhere.
The problem can cause some CSS with "*" sign, for example:

```
.column *{
  color:#000000;
}
```

Maybe this can be the cause. I once wasted a lot of time searching for errors because of these asterisks...

Comment: That's what I thought, but Firebug shows that the color: #FFFFFF style is not overriden and on the "computed" tab it shows color: 000000

Comment: I don't use !important anywhere, jquery-ui stylesheet is included last and my own styles don't specify text color anywhere.

Comment: `<form id="runArguments" class="ui-widget" style="">
<fieldset class="ui-widget-content">
<legend class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Run command arguments</legend>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="partition">Partition</label>
</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>`

Comment: Ok, I figured it out - i just had to apply ui-widget-content to <td> elements.